# How to disable kafka consumer on basis of a global flag

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a use case where I want to control the kafka consumer through global flag.

In kafka consumer i have added the condition if flag is true then only i am creating the container factory.

but kafka consumer still tries to create kafka consumer how to control in that case.

below i have shared both kafka consumer config class and kafka consumer class.

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

  public static final String LOCALHOST_9200 = "localhost:9200";
  public static final String KAFKA_BROKERS = "KAFKA_BROKERS";
  private final String KAFKA_ENDPOINT =
      StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(System.getenv(KAFKA_BROKERS)) ? LOCALHOST_9200
          : System.getenv(KAFKA_BROKERS);

  private final boolean KAFKA_CONSUMER_ENABLED = Boolean.parseBoolean(
      System.getenv("KAFKA_CONSUMER_ENABLED"));

  @Bean
  public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
    System.out.println(System.getenv(KAFKA_BROKERS));
    System.out.println(KAFKA_CONSUMER_ENABLED);
    System.out.println("KafkEndpoint :: "+ KAFKA_ENDPOINT);
    if (!KAFKA_CONSUMER_ENABLED) {
      return null;
    }
    Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, KAFKA_ENDPOINT);
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config);
  }

  @Bean
  public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    if (!KAFKA_CONSUMER_ENABLED) {
      return null;
    }
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    return factory;
  }
}
```

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class KafkaPayrollDocUpdateConsumer {

  private final boolean KAFKA_CONSUMER_ENABLED = Boolean.parseBoolean(
      System.getenv("KAFKA_CONSUMER_ENABLED"));

  @KafkaListener(topics = "#{T(java.lang.System).getenv('NODE_ENV') + '-doc-centre-doc-create-update-event'}", groupId = "doc-centre-doc-create-update-event", containerFactory = "concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
  public void listen(String message) {
    

  }
}
```

Comment: how do I control Kafka consumer - how to stop consumers getting called on new messages every time?

Comment: You can add `autoStartup = "false"`, for example to the listener annotation. Try putting your SPEL condition there. Otherwise, keep it false and use a rest controller to start/stop the listener container (you can find examples in the spring-kafka docs)

Comment: `autoStartup = "#{T(System).getenv('KAFKA_CONSUMER_ENABLED')?:false}"`

Comment: Btw, adding NODE_ENV in a Java project seems odd

Answer (score 0):

Use `autoStartup` with SpEL and an Elvis operator

```java
@KafkaListener(topics = "#{T(java.lang.System).getenv('NODE_ENV') + '-doc-centre-doc-create-update-event'}", groupId = "doc-centre-doc-create-update-event", containerFactory = "concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    autoStartup = "#{T(System).getenv('KAFKA_CONSUMER_ENABLED')?:false}"
```